# Как передать параметры в событийную внешнюю функцию jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно, чтобы при скроле каждый раз прогонялся код с параметрами.

Так не работает:

```
function my_scroll(a,b){
    console.log(a + b);
};

$(window).scroll(my_scroll(1,2));
```

Так тоже:

```
function my_scroll(a,b){
    console.log(a + b);
};

$(window).scroll(my_scroll,1,2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо передать функцию, а у вас происходит вызов.

Для решения этой проблемы проще всего обернуть вызов в еще одну функцию.

пример:

```
function my_scroll(a,b){
    console.log(a + b);
};

$(window).scroll(()=>my_scroll(1,2)); // здесь вызов my_scroll обернут в стрелочную функцию, тем самым она не вызывается, а передается.
```

Comment: Вот бы еще без jQuery))

Answer (score 0):

**Вот вариант без JQ (на мой взгляд так даже короче):**

```
    function my_scroll(a,b){
        console.log(a + b);
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>my_scroll(1,2));
```

Comment: Добавьте лучше в прежний ответ.

Comment: @Leonid а есть какая-то значимая разница?)